# Websockets distributed tracing solution

Tags: asp.net-core, websocket, open-telemetry, distributed-tracing

How to add distributed tracing to websockets properly?

As each websocket connection is long lived, a lot of messages ends up getting traced under one activity. Is there any way to split that? (See below link for reference)

Looks like there is an issue written on [.netcore github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/29846) related to this but while it is getting fixed we want to have an interim fix. Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Comment: Hi, did you use the pure Websockets or Signalr? Some helpful links you can have a try: [Accept WebSocket requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-6.0#accept-websocket-requests) and [Use hub filters in ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hub-filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: I'm using pure websockets. And able to accept the websockets requests properly. Want to know how can we add tracing to them properly.